# Create a menu with click and hover functionalty using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add both click and hover functionality to a menu. My existing Javascript that activates the menu drop down on click is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
            if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
                $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
                $(this).next().slideToggle();
                $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried to use jquery to add simultaneous hover triggering by putting into the head of the page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>$("#nav").bind("click hover", fn);</script>
```

amongst other things, and predictably none of them worked. I clearly have no idea what I'm doing! The working page without the jquery additions is [here](http://www.davidkneale.com/wcusa/expeditions.html) and the menu is down the left hand side of the page. If anyone can spare me advice it would be much appreciated!

Comment: There are probably hundreds of tutorials on Google that will outline exactly how to do what you want. Try one, and come ask if you have any problems along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating to latest Jquery, and then read about [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )
```

> **events**: One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces,
>   such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".

So basically I think you can exchange `.click` for `.on`, and use events `click mouseover`.

#### Edit

In your source page the Jquery version is `1.4.2`, just for noticing.

Comment: This works well.
  `$(function(){ 
   $('#nav > li > ul')
    .hide()
    .click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('#nav > li').toggle(function(){
    $(this)
    .removeClass('waiting')
    .find('ul').slideDown();
  }, function(){
    $(this)
    .removeClass('waiting')
    .find('ul').slideUp();
  });
$('#nav > li').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('waiting');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#nav .waiting')
      .click()
      .removeClass('waiting');
      },800);
    }, function(){
      $('#nav .waiting').removeClass('waiting');
    });
});
</script>`

Comment: Only thing I'm not sure about is how to close the sub-menu of the previously triggered menu item when another one is clicked/hovered over.

Comment: @Nilcot. That is awesome! Is it possible to add a timeout function to this?

Comment: Sorry Niloct! What I would like is a timeout function that provides a delay before the list expands out on hover.

Comment: Thanks. I've added .delay(800);` to `$('#nav li ul').slideUp()` but its a bit all over the place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16215/discussion-between-niloct-and-david-kneale)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pre-built solution instead of creating your own solution from scratch.

See Superfish - http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/.

Superfish is a jQuery plugin that handles click/hover dropdown menus.

For a css-only drop-down menu, search "Suckerfish". Superfish can be used on top of suckerfish for graceful degradation in case the user does not have javascript enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked the best for my needs:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#nav > li > ul')
.hide()
.click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#nav > li').toggle(function(){
$(this)
.removeClass('waiting')
.find('ul').slideDown();
}, function(){
$(this)
.removeClass('waiting')
.find('ul').slideUp();
});

$('#nav > li').hover(function(){
$(this).addClass('waiting');
 setTimeout(function(){
$('#nav .waiting')
.click()
.removeClass('waiting');
},600);
}, function(){
$('#nav .waiting').removeClass('waiting');
});
});
</script>`
```

@Niloct helped me find a way to close the sub-menu of the previously triggered menu item but it resulted in the menu being a bit impractical. Thanks!